# Reducing risks of interior brick wall insulation?

Tags: insulation, brick

I was surprised to learn that that there are risks with insulating the interior walls in older all-brick houses - particularly in cold climates. This article outlines some of the issues:

http://www.greenbuildingadvisor.com/blogs/dept/musings/insulating-old-brick-buildings

To summarize, the risks are:

- Wooden joists sitting on (the now colder) brick will be wet from moist air condensing on the brick and the ends can rot
- The inner layer (wythe) of brick will not be able to dry inwards. If the brick remains wet, it could fail (especially with freeze/thaw cycles)

These issues sound reasonable - however, articles refer to insulation in all-or-nothing terms. I'm wondering if there is some middle ground, to add some insulation to save some energy and increase comfort, without much risk of damaging the brick?

- Could a vapour barrier be omitted, to allow for the brick to dry inwards?
- Can a reduced level of insulation be used so the brick will still be warmed by the heat of the house?
- Can walls have gaps in the insulation? e.g. leaving 12 inches at the top to warm the brick and help keep the joist ends dry?
- Would techniques recommend for basement insulation be applicable? (e.g. use EPS or XPS board)

Any other safer options for interior insulation in an all-brick house?

Comment: I have found that just a small airgap behind basement walls do as much good as adding insulation because there is no air movement. As far as the block failing because of freeze thaw cycles I have never seen that happen.